# Unable to assign this e-mail address to the list, because the address is in use.

Tags: 2010, incoming-email

How do I get rid of this error... I disabled an re-enabled the incoming mail settings in a document library.  When type in the alias i get this error: **Unable to assign this e-mail address to the list, because the address is in use.**

Answer (score 1):

There is another Document Library with the same email address. Even if you have deleted old Document Library it might still be in the Recycle bin somewhere.

Comment: I used the email on the wrong document library, but I couldn't move it. I just had to wait a few minutes.